# How to solve output underflow error using naudiodon / portaudio?

Tags: node.js, stream, wav, portaudio

I am writing a small node.js program that will be able to play wav sound files on a chosen audio device.
The sound starts well but it is stoped before the end of the file.

Here is my code :

```
const fs = require("fs");
const wav = require("wav");
const portAudio = require("naudiodon");

const ao = new portAudio.AudioIO({
    outOptions: {
        channelCount: 2,
        sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat24Bit,
        sampleRate: 44100,
    }
});

const name = "myfile.wav";
const file = fs.createReadStream(`./sounds/${name}`);

const reader = new wav.Reader();

reader.on("format", () => {
    reader.pipe(ao);
    ao.start();
});

file.pipe(reader);

process.on("SIGINT", ao.quit);
```

When I modify the `highWaterMark` option of `fs.createReadStream`, it slightly change the cut position in the sound but it never goes until the end of it.
I always get a `portAudio status - output underflow` log error.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing a similar error, and my solution was to manually write to the AudioIO stream instead of using the pipe commands.

So instead of

```
reader.on("format", () => {
    reader.pipe(ao);
    ao.start();
});
```

You would use

```
ao.start();
reader.on("data",chunk=>ao.write(chunk));
```

Output underflow is generally not an issue, but to avoid it I initialised a new instance of PortAudio before playing every file, however that is only applicable if you don't care about slight latency.